# going through devstack, compute node not showing up in OS interface

Tags: devstack

I really need help with setting up a [controller and a few compute nodes with Devstack](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html).

After executing the `stack.sh` on both the controller and the computer node I expect to have a OpenStack interface on the IP `192.168.122.13/ dashboard/project/api_access/` which I got successfully and a compute node on the IP `192.168.122.12` which will show up as a machine on the OpenStack interface (on `192.168.122.13`). But I do not see the machine `192.168.122.12` in the OpenStack interface.

What is worse is that the IP `192.168.122.13` is listed as a compute node:

[image]

Here is my `local.conf` on the controller node:

```
HOST_IP=192.168.122.13
FIXED_RANGE=10.4.128.0/20
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.122.128/25
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
ADMIN_PASSWORD=mnbmnbmn
DATABASE_PASSWORD=mnbmnbmn
RABBIT_PASSWORD=mnbmnbmn
SERVICE_PASSWORD=mnbmnbmn
```

And here is the `loca.conf` on the compute node:

```
HOST_IP=192.168.122.12
FIXED_RANGE=10.4.128.0/20
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.122.128/25
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
ADMIN_PASSWORD=mnbmnbmn
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
SERVICE_HOST=192.168.122.13
MYSQL_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
RABBIT_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$SERVICE_HOST:9292
ENABLED_SERVICES=n-cpu,q-agt,c-vol,placement-client
NOVA_VNC_ENABLED=True
NOVNCPROXY_URL="http://$SERVICE_HOST:6080/vnc_lite.html"
VNCSERVER_LISTEN=$HOST_IP
VNCSERVER_PROXYCLIENT_ADDRESS=$VNCSERVER_LISTEN
```

Here is the output after running the `stack.sh` script on the compute node:

```
=========================
DevStack Component Timing
 (times are in seconds)
=========================
run_process            3
apt-get-update         1
osc                    0
wait_for_service       2
pip_install           37
apt-get                5
-------------------------
Unaccounted time      59
=========================
Total runtime        107



This is your host IP address: 192.168.122.12
This is your host IPv6 address: ::1

WARNING:
Using lib/neutron-legacy is deprecated, and it will be removed in the future


Services are running under systemd unit files.
For more information see:
https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/systemd.html

DevStack Version: train
Change: 1b35581bb096883ceafbfeea286153eaec184c17 Use SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib for global pip installs 2020-08-31 16:09:16 +0200
OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
```

I am running DevStack from the branch `stable/train`.

Does anyone here has any suggestions?

Furthermore, when I run the command `for i in $(seq 2 10); do /usr/local/bin/nova-manage fixed reserve 10.4.128.$i; done`

```
               ...
nova-manage: error: argument category: invalid choice: 'fixed' (choose from 'version', 'bash-completion', 'placement', 'network', 'cell_v2', 'db', 'floating', 'api_db')
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had some similar issues like the one you described.

To begin with, `192.168.122.13` correctly appears as a Compute node, as DevStack's original purpose is for all-in-one installations. Hence, the Nova Compute service is installed by default in your Controller node.

Secondly, after Ocata version, for the compute hosts of the cells to be discovered, there are two options:

1. Manually execute:

   `# su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova`
2. Add the following line under the **[scheduler]** segment of **/etc/nova/nova.conf** in your controller node:

   `discover_hosts_in_cells_interval = 60`

   Then restart Nova-related services (Compute, Scheduler, Conductor):

   `sudo systemctl restart devstack@n-*`

I suggest the second option, which will periodically search for undiscovered compute hosts, so it will cover your needs even if you need to add an additional Compute node in the future.

Thirdly, in the **local.conf** of your Compute node, I can see that **n-api-meta** is not included in the enabled plugins. I would suggest to include it, run `./unstack.sh` and `./stack.sh` again and retry running the command:

`for i in $(seq 2 10); do /usr/local/bin/nova-manage fixed reserve 10.4.128.$i; done`

This command is intended for reservation of the first 10 IPs in your private subnet, hence, even if it fails you will still be able to know if your setup is operational.

Comment: Hey. I did all of it, nothing appears in the interface `http://192.168.122.13/dashboard/project/instances/`

Comment: Also, running `for i in $(seq 2 10); do /usr/local/bin/nova-manage fixed reserve 10.4.128.$i; done` gives the following error as stated above: `nova-manage: error: argument category: invalid choice: 'fixed' (choose from 'version', 'bash-completion', 'placement', 'network', 'cell_v2', 'db', 'floating', 'api_db')`

Comment: Honestly this devstack seems to be total garbage. I'll just use ovirt probably to learn how to do virtualization

Comment: @JeniaIvanov Do you mean that the Compute node does not appear? Did you check under Admin -> Hypervisors on the sidebar?

Comment: Hey Railis. Thank you kindly for time and help but I abandoned the endeavor after an intense effort. Looks like the devstack is a pile of non working scripts that are not suitable for learning anything. I'm going to use OVirt instead spawn multiple VMs to learn Terraform and Ansible and other such technologie.